# Add sorting by modified date in Woocommerce products sort by

Tags: php, sorting, woocommerce, product, datemodified

In woocommerce, I would like to add the possibility to sort the products by "Modified date" in shop and archives pages.

How can I add "Sort By date modified " in woocommerce product sorting dropdown?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done very easily with the following code, which will add a sorting by modified date:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'enable_catalog_ordering_by_modified_date' );
function enable_catalog_ordering_by_modified_date( $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        if ( 'modified_date' == $_GET['orderby'] ) {
            return array(
                'orderby'  => 'modified',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
            );
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_catalog_orderby_by_modified_date' );
function add_catalog_orderby_by_modified_date( $orderby_options ) {
    // Rename 'menu_order' label
    $orderby_options['modified_date'] = __("Sort by modified date", "woocommerce");

    return $orderby_options ;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: LoicTheAztec: Thank you. Its work very good. But How can we set this sorting as default in woocommerce? Tahnks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yest i tesed it and it works. But I don't know how to set the modified sorting as woocommerce default sorting. can you help me? Best regards.

Comment: works beautifully. I wanted to show the products from the newest to the eldest published so I changed the DESC to ASC