# Add products sorting option by star rating ASC in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I'm looking for a way to sort the products by star rating (asc and desc). It seems that i would need to create a custom code for this since something like this for example isn't implemented in Woocommerce.

`$options['rating-asc']` is a the piece of code that doesn't work/exist but i use it to express the function i'm looking for like `$options['title-desc']`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'rory_add_custom_sorting_options' );

function rory_add_custom_sorting_options( $options ){
    $options['rating-asc'] = 'Rating (Asc)';
    return $options;
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define `'rating-asc'` sorting options arguments in a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` hook.

As sorting option **"Sort by average rating"** exists, if you look to default existing arguments for sorting products by "rating" key, you have that array:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
         'ID' => 'ASC'
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => '_wc_average_rating'
);
```

So you just need to change `'meta_value_num' => 'DESC'` to `'meta_value_num' => 'ASC'`, then your right working code is going to be like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'enable_catalog_ordering_by_ratings' );
function enable_catalog_ordering_by_ratings( $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && 'rating-asc' === $_GET['orderby']
    && isset($args['orderby']['meta_value_num']) ) {
       $args['orderby']['meta_value_num'] = 'ASC';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Now you can insert your new sorting option just after **"Sort by average rating"** existing one like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'catalog_orderby_ratings_asc_filter' );
function catalog_orderby_ratings_asc_filter( $options ){
    $sorted_options =[];

    foreach( $options as $key => $label ){
        if( 'rating' === $key ) {
            $sorted_options['rating'] = $options['rating'] . ' ' . __('(Desc)', 'woocommerce');
            $sorted_options['rating-asc'] = $options['rating'] . ' ' . __('(Asc)', 'woocommerce');
        } else {
            $sorted_options[$key] = $label;
        }
    }

    return $sorted_options;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Related:

- [Add a new custom default ordering catalog option in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273655/add-a-new-custom-default-ordering-catalog-option-in-woocommerce/52275842#52275842)
- [Set custom product sorting as default Woocommerce sorting option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589711/set-custom-product-sorting-as-default-woocommerce-sorting-option/53589762#53589762)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work only for adding the sorting option to the dropdown, but if you want it to have effect you need to link it to a meta key or something by adding the correct arguments to the catalog products query like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'rory_custom_sorting_args' );
 
function rory_custom_sorting_args( $args ) {
 
    if( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && 'rating-asc' === $_GET['orderby'] ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'rating-asc'; // Replace this with the meta key you want to use for ordering products
        $args['orderby'] = array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC' );
    }
 
    return $args;
 }
```